# See if the same subscriptions which come at a company PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

```
if(isset($_POST['Klant'])){
        try {
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT (SELECT KltBedrijfsNaam from [tbl relaties] where KltId = auoKltId) as Naam,  auoId, auoNaam  from dbo.tblAutomatischeOrder where auoNaam  in (
                select auoNaam from dbo.tblAutomatischeOrder group by auoNaam having count(*) > 1
                    ) and  auoStatus= 'LO';"); 
            $stmt->execute();

            $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            ?>
                <div  class="insert_container2">
                    <h2>Klanten Tabel</h2>  
                    <p>Zoeken op bedrijven!</p>

                    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Zoeken van bedrijven... ">              
                    <table class="w3-table w3-striped w3-bordered w3-border w3-margin-top"  id="myTable">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Bedrijf </th>
                        <th>ID van abbo </th>
                        <th>Abbo naam </th>
                    </tr>
                <?php
                foreach ($results as $row) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['Naam']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['auoId']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['auoNaam']."</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
                ?>
                </table>
            <?php
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
        $conn = null;
        echo "</table>";
```

}[The table of select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G357p.png)

The convenience does not come, I get all companies that have more than 1 subscriptions. I want the select query indicates precisely whether a company has two single subscriptions

Comment: Please clarify. What makes the two last items special? And your output is difficult to read, use field and line separators. Even your code is hard to read...

Comment: there are the same auoNaam of the Naam, is this better to read

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_. It's not at all clear what you're asking above, can you edit your question to clarify?

Comment: is this al ready cleader or?

Answer (score 0):

The question is still unclear, why are just those two cases special? I'll take a guess: You want cases where first and third field are equal and that have more than one instance.

```
mysql> SELECT a, b, c FROM t WHERE (a,c) IN 
  (SELECT a, c 
   FROM t 
   GROUP BY a, c 
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
);
+------+------+------+
| a    | b    | c    |
+------+------+------+
| aa   | 1    | qq   |
| aa   | 2    | qq   |
+------+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM t;
+------+------+------+
| a    | b    | c    |
+------+------+------+
| aa   | 1    | qq   |
| aa   | 2    | qq   |
| bb   | 3    | qq   |
| bb   | 4    | ww   |
| cc   | 5    | ee   |
| cc   | 6    | qq   |
+------+------+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```